# Can a single workflow be spread across multiple endpoints?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Say we have two workflows having some common functionality.
Workflow A has a service contract `InterfaceA` and Workflow B has `InterfaceB`.

Both workflows are hosted within a single service through the different endpoints respectively.

I know that it is possible to extract common functionality into the separate interface `InterfaceC` and make `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` inherit from it. The clients then could use `InterfaceC` to invoke common functions for both workflows.

I have been asked to create a separate endpoint for the `InterfaceC` without having `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB` inheriting form it. i.e.

- common functionality is moved to `InterfaceC`
- workflow A and B activities updated to use `InterfaceC` contract where common bits are used
- specific functionality is still exposed via A and B interfaces.

Is this possible to have three endpoints (same bindings), but two workflows?

The only thing possible I can think of is to move common functionality into a separate Workflow C using `InterfaceC` contract and use some correlation mechanism to instantiate workflows between A and C as well as B and C. But that is not what is required.